# Perl (difference between windows and linux)

Tags: windows, linux, perl, activeperl

I use the following Perl code without any problems in Ubuntu, but when I try it in XP using activeperl it hangs, no error messages, just a blank screen. Are there any issues I should be aware of when moving code between standard perl and active perl or windows and ubuntu?

```
*sub do_search
{
 my $term = shift @_;
 my $page = 1;
 my @results;
 while (scalar @results < $opts{maxresults})
 {
  my $rset = $handle->search({query=>$term, page => $page, rpp => $opts{rpp} });
  print "Searching for $term (page $page)\n" if $opts{verbose};
  if (ref $rset eq 'HASH' && exists $rset->{results})
  {
   # break out if no results came back
   last unless @{$rset->{results}};
   push @results, @{$rset->{results}};
   printf "Now we have %d entries\n", scalar @results if $opts{verbose};
  }
  # go to the next page
  $page++;
 }
 print_post($_) foreach @results;
}*
```

source:http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/l-perl-twitter/index.html

-Thanks

Comment: I've seen perl freak out over line endings in scripts.  Usually, though, it'll just show an error message, not hang the interpreter.

Comment: You should isolate line where it hangs

Answer (score 2):

There is quite extensive manual page about Windows-specific perl problems - [perlwin32](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlwin32.html).

Only non-core package the script is using is [Net::Twitter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aTwitter), which seems to have good test results under Windows - [platform test matrix](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Net-Twitter+3.15000).